# How to Restart my Previous Activity from Next Activity

Tags: java, android

I have critical stage can anyone help if you know,Actually i have 1 to 5 activities and 6th one is common activity,first i need to go 1st activity  to 6th activity,Now my doubt is  in 6th activity having one refresh button for activity 1st activity  but its not working in my code,i have used 
_Try_Again.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            /*Intent loginIntent = new Intent(Inter_Conn_Error_activity.this,
                    Splashscreen.class);
            startActivity(loginIntent);*/
            onBackPressed();
            finish();
        }
    });...
```

How can i do this? please help me..

Comment: try out finish() method for Refresh button it will switch you again fron=m 6 to 1 activity

Comment: "one *refresh* button for activity 1"? Please elaborate. What are you exactly trying to do? What is your code? What have you tried and what is the activity stack?

Comment: For Eg:i have 3 diff kind of activities and i have 1 common activity,i gone that common activity form 1st activity,than Now i want come back to my previous activity..because i need to restart my previous activity..shall you understand..

Answer (score 0):

I cant get the problem u r facing...
But as i understand it then:

1 to 6
intent (this,6)

6 to 1
intent or finish()

6 to 6
intent or call onCreate method

Comment: i used so many activities.. for eg: sampl1.activity to net_con.activity than i need to back to sampl1.activity and sample2.activity to net_con.activity than now i need to go sample2.activity..sry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

for this use the attribute,
Putextra

when u try to go common activity take the avivity name with it.

when u try to come back to previous activity
check which activity it came...

Comment: take the activity name in put extra attribute

Answer (score 0):

You could override the onActivityResult callback from the calling activity. Once the new activity finishes, the onActivityResult kicks in and you could use it.

Eg:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int,int, Intent)
{
// YOUR CODE
}
```